# How do I resume installing additional node.js tools successfully without starting a duplicate chocolatey installation?

Tags: python, node.js

I lost my internet connection while installing additional tools for node.js. using the automatic installation option. I'm new to programming and trying to set up an environment for JavaScript on VS Code. I rebooted my system and tried resuming the installation through the Install Additional Tools for Node.js cmd prompt, but it gives a warning that there is already an existing chocolatey installation detected and thus not continuing installation. Furthermore, 2 packages failed to be upgraded from the initial error when the connection was lost, but now it says one package failed yet still showing 0/2 packages were upgraded? I uninstalled node.js and reinstalled it but it hasn't solved the issue. Is visualstudio2019-workload-vctools the only thing missing? Of which I could maybe try installing it manually? Or are the files now corrupted and I have to start over since installation didn't complete?
I don't want to mess with chocolatey itself (by uninstalling) as I read that it can destroy your pc. If there are still a few more tools or packages to install and files not corrupted, how do I successfully and safely resume the installation of all necessary tools? Python 3.10 looks to be successfully installed.
This is the message on PowerShell and the screenshot is attached as well:

"WARNING: 'choco' was found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe'.
WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue.
For security reasons, this script will not overwrite existing installations.

Please use choco upgrade chocolatey to handle upgrades of Chocolatey itself.
Chocolatey v1.1.0
Upgrading the following packages:
python;visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
python v3.10.5 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools is not installed. Installing...
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools not installed. An error occurred during installation:
The remote server returned an error: (524).
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools package files upgrade failed with exit code 1. Performing other installation steps.
The upgrade of visualstudio2019-workload-vctools was NOT successful.
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools not installed. An error occurred during installation:
The remote server returned an error: (524).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures

- visualstudio2019-workload-vctools (exited 1) - visualstudio2019-workload-vctools not installed. An error occurred during installation:
  The remote server returned an error: (524).
  Type ENTER to exit:"

[PowerShell-chocolatey error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP6qm.jpg)

I am thinking the failure is due to the fact that I don't have visual studio 2019? It seems like everything else is fine. I'm setting up using VS Code. It doesn't seem like the issue had anything to do with me losing connection. I have attached a screenshot of the successful vs failed installations.
[additional node.js tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJhK5.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rerun: D:\path\to\nodejs\install_tools.bat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLeux.png)